# How can I find the minimal circle include some given points?

Tags: algorithm, 2d

I have given some points (2D-coordinates) and want to find the smallest circle, that includes all of this points. The algorithm doesn't have to be very efficient (while it would be nice naturally).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Smallest circle which covers given points on 2D plane](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901535/smallest-circle-which-covers-given-points-on-2d-plane); there is an identical answer by the same user, and the other question has better wording, in my opinion. The link-only answer in this version is also not great...

Answer (score 7):

This is the so-called *Smallest Enclosing Balls* problem (in your case, *Smallest Enclosing Circle*), a.k.a. *Miniball*. There are several algorithms and implementations out there for this problem – all of the following are linear-time solutions (i.e., given *n* balls, they run in *O(n)* if you consider the dimension *d* fixed, *d=2* in your case):

- For 2D and 3D, [Gärtner's implementation](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gaertner/miniball.html) is probably the fastest.
- For higher dimensions (up to 10,000, say), take a look at https://github.com/hbf/miniball, which is the implementation of an algorithm by Gärtner, Kutz, and Fischer (note: I am one of the co-authors).
- For very, very high dimensions, *core-set* (approximation) algorithms will be faster.

**Note:** If you are looking for an algorithm to compute the smallest enclosing sphere *of spheres*, you will find a C++ implementation in the [Computational Geometry Algorithms Library (CGAL)](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Bounding_volumes/Chapter_main.html). (You do not need to use all of CGAL; simply extract the required header and source files.)