# Smallest circle which covers given points on 2D plane

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Problem: **What is the smallest possible diameter of a circle which covers given N points on a 2D plane?**

What is the most efficient algorithm to solve this problem and how does it work?

Comment: This has been asked before. If only I could find it though.

Comment: This should be the __Smallest circle problem__, take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_circle_problem

Comment: Here is the "duplicate", although like mine it's not a fantastic answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102547/how-can-i-find-the-minimal-circle-include-some-given-points

Comment: Nayuki.io has this script: https://www.nayuki.io/page/smallest-enclosing-circle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the [smallest circle problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smallest_circle_problem). See the references for the links to the suggested algorithms.

> E.Welzl, Smallest Enclosing Disks
>   (Balls and Ellipsoids), in H. Maurer
>   (Ed.), New Results and New Trends in
>   Computer Science, Lecture Notes in
>   Computer Science, Vol. 555,
>   Springer-Verlag, 359–37 (1991)

is the reference to the "fastest" algorithm.

Comment: Thanks! I guess this answer can be included in the original question, to remove the duplicate.

Answer (score 6):

There are several algorithms and implementations out there for the *Smallest enclosing balls* problem.

- For 2D and 3D, [Gärtner's implementation](http://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/gaertner/miniball.html) is probably the fastest.
- For higher dimensions (up to 10,000, say), take a look at https://github.com/hbf/miniball, which is the implementation of an algorithm by Gärtner, Kutz, and Fischer (note: I am one of the co-authors).
- For very, very high dimensions, *core-set* (approximation) algorithms will be faster.

**Note:** If you are looking for an algorithm to compute the smallest enclosing sphere *of spheres*, you will find a C++ implementation in the [Computational Geometry Algorithms Library (CGAL)](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/latest/doc_html/cgal_manual/Bounding_volumes/Chapter_main.html). (You do not need to use all of CGAL; simply extract the required header and source files.)

Comment: How well would this algorithm work for points on the surface of a sphere? I'm trying to solve this for geolocation.

Answer (score 1):

the furthest point voronoi diagram approach

```
http://www.dma.fi.upm.es/mabellanas/tfcs/fvd/algorithm.html
```

turns out to work really well for the 2 d problem.  It is non-iterative and (pretty sure) guaranteed exact.   I suspect it doesn't extend so well to higher dimensions, which is why there is little attention to it in the literature.

If there is interest i'll describe it here - the above link is a bit hard to follow I think.

edit another link: http://ojs.statsbiblioteket.dk/index.php/daimipb/article/view/6704