# Vectorizing OpenCV loops python

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I am writing a simple helper function that loops through all the contours found and do certain operations on them. My question is, is there a way to vectorize this for loop to make the code more efficient

```
def TL(contours):
    k = 0
    for j, cnt in enumerate(contours):
        k =+ 1
        # x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
        # r = w/h
        # if r <= 1.2*2.142 and r >= 0.8*2.142:
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.01*cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), True)

        if area > 50 and cv2.isContourConvex(cnt) == False and len(approx)<=15 and len(approx)>=8: # and len(approx)>=8  
            # cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            (xc,yc),radius = cv2.minEnclosingCircle(cnt)
            # cv2.circle(frame,(int(xc),int(yc)),int(radius*0.9),(0,255,0),2)
            # TARGET = (xc,yc-radius-1)
            # nearest = find_nearest_white(TARGET)
            h = int(radius*4)
            w = int(h*2.25)
            x = int(xc-(1/3)*w)
            y = int(yc-h/2)

            if w*h <= 4000:
                cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
            continue

    return frame
```

Comment: Which part of it takes the most time?

Comment: @JohnZwinck the minEnclosing circle.

Comment: Not really because these aren't numpy functions. This really shouldn't be that slow though, how large of images are these?

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds the resolution for the picture is 1920x1080 but the contours are usually 100×10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a set of contours and the slowest part of your code (according to your comment) is `cv2.minEnclosingCircle()`.

I can see two major approaches:

1. Look at the implementation of `cv2.minEnclosingCircle()` and see if you can build a faster one (for your inputs).  Some algorithms are mentioned here: [How can I find the minimal circle include some given points?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102547/how-can-i-find-the-minimal-circle-include-some-given-points/)
2. Use multiple threads (with the GIL released) or multiple processes.  The `cv2.minEnclosingCircle()` calls can be done in parallel (perhaps ahead of time), as they are all independent.